# Creating a Google script to send automated emails based on a cell value every day

Tags: java

I have a Google sheet with Deals, Deal Owners, Status of the deals columns. I would like a script that sends automated emails every morning at 6am if the status contains 'delay' text.

I built a code where it sends emails to all emails from the range, I don't know the command to send only to the email addresses where the status is delayed.

I ideally would like to compile all DELAYED DEALS as a list with Deal number, and status as one email to the Deal owner rather than individual emails per line. Thanks

Comment: Please add to your post the code you have created so far.

Comment: You could try out apache poi for reading the excel files, which supports xls and xlsx. And take a look at mailtrap if you want to use a mail server.